# the executed order of recursion function in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

```
def fac(n):
    if n==1 or n==2  or n==3:
        print "i am calling fac(",n,")"
        return  n
    else:
        print "i am calling fac(",n,")"
        x=fac(n-1)+fac(n-2)+fac(n-3)
        return  x
```

The output of fac(6)  is :

```
fac(6)
i am calling fac( 6 )
i am calling fac( 5 )
i am calling fac( 4 )
i am calling fac( 3 )
i am calling fac( 2 )
i am calling fac( 1 )
i am calling fac( 3 )
i am calling fac( 2 )
i am calling fac( 4 )
i am calling fac( 3 )
i am calling fac( 2 )
i am calling fac( 1 )
i am calling fac( 3 )
20
```

What is the rule for python2.7 to execute the recursion function?
The result confused me，it can not be analysed from the calculation tree.
Why the result is not  other forms?

What is the rule for python to deal with recursion calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python runs each call in the order it encounters the instruction to call it. So, starting at the top of `fac` with `n=6`, it will get to this line:

```
x=fac(n-1)+fac(n-2)+fac(n-3)
```

The first thing it will do is to calculate `n-1=5`, and run `fac(5)` - which starts again at the top of the function. It will reach the same place and call `fac(4)`, which will call `fac(3)` - which just returns 3. Only now will it calculate `n-2=2` and run `fac(2)`, and then `fac(1)` and do the addition. Now `fac(4)` has finished, we're back in `fac(5)` and we keep going from `fac(n-2)`.

If you modify your function to keep track of how deeply recursed you are, you can print the calls as a tree structure so you can see what's going on more easily:

```
def fac(n, level=0):
    print '{}fac({})'.format(level*'\t', n)

    if n==1 or n==2  or n==3:
        return n
    else:
        x = fac(n-1, level+1) + fac(n-2, level+1) + fac(n-3, level+1)
    return x
```

gives:

```
fac(6)
   fac(5)
      fac(4)
          fac(3)
          fac(2)
          fac(1)
      fac(3)
      fac(2)
   fac(4)
      fac(3)
      fac(2)
      fac(1)
   fac(3)
```